# Nokogiri: irregular divs

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Trying to deal with irregular content in `div` elements. Namely what comes after the `h3` titles. There is no set content under the h3 headings. However, I need to associate whatever text is there with the heading. There could be a ul or just a span or both. The main thing is not combining all the text under the h3 headings.

I have been able to navigate to my `div` using the .css operator. Each `div` contains one or more of 4 `h3` headings followed by a comment or a list if there is more than one comment.

How can I separate whatever follows a `h3` tag ending before the next tag (if there is one)?

You can see a sample of the `div` I'm working with here (I can grab whatever is between the `h2` because its the same for every `div`):

```
   <div class="inspection_container">
  <h2 class="inspection_date_title">
    <div class="calendar_list">
      <span>Mar</span><strong>4</strong>
    </div>Routine Inspection<small>Inspected Mar. 4, 2014</small>
  </h2>
  <h3>Actions taken by inspector</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="Comment">
      <strong>Consultation / Technical Assistance</strong><p>Instructions are given to the owner/operator to assist them with taking the proper actions to meet regulations.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="inspection_container">
  <h2 class="inspection_date_title">
    <div class="calendar_list">
      <span>Sep</span><strong>4</strong>
    </div>Re-inspection<small>Inspected Sep. 4, 2013</small>
  </h2>
  <h3>Not in compliance</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="X">
      <strong>Premise is clean/sanitary</strong><p>Food premise is to be maintained in a clean and sanitary condition.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Actions taken by inspector</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="Comment">
      <strong>Consultation / Technical Assistance</strong><p>Instructions are given to the owner/operator to assist them with taking the proper actions to meet regulations.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="inspection_container">
  <h2 class="inspection_date_title">
    <div class="calendar_list">
      <span>Aug</span><strong>30</strong>
    </div>Routine Inspection<small>Inspected Aug. 30, 2013</small>
  </h2>
  <h3>Not in compliance</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="X">
      <strong>Washrooms are cleaned regularly</strong><p>Washrooms are to be kept clean, sanitary, in good repair and must be supplied with liquid soap in a dispenser, single service/paper towels, cloth roller towel or hot air dryer and hot and cold running water.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="X">
      <strong>Building interior is well-maintained</strong><p>Walls, floors and ceilings are to be maintained and in good repair.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="X">
      <strong>Premise is clean/sanitary</strong><p>Food premise is to be maintained in a clean and sanitary condition.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Actions taken by inspector</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="Comment">
      <strong>Consultation / Technical Assistance</strong><p>Instructions are given to the owner/operator to assist them with taking the proper actions to meet regulations.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show a sample HTML snippet.

Comment: Don't give us a link to the data, provide a minimal snippet that demonstrates the problem. Links break, making your question turn into nonsense; Examples will always be useful to others once your question has been answered. Plus, giving us a link assumes we'll chase down the needed information necessary to help you, but instead they tend to discourage people who would answer you, so help us help you.

Comment: sorry. I put up a sample div. This shows 2 possible h3 headings out of 4, with no way of knowing which ones will appear.

Comment: What information do you want to extract? Please edit your question and describe how you identify the information you need.

Comment: While it's good to see the three `<div>` tags as a "minimal snippet", those don't constitute valid HTML, which is necessary also. And, while the HTML helps, we don't really know what you want from it, so please show a sample output so we have a goal to work toward. Without that, you'll see a variety of solutions which have to be shoehorned into your code.

Comment: Sorry, but this is the chunk I'm actually working with (having hived it off of the page), so the other html is irrelevant. What I need is: {"Actions taken by inspector" => "some text\nlist element\nlist element\n...", "other heading" => "any text\nany more text\nanymoretext", "other random heading" => ...}  I don't care if the text was in a list or whatever or combination of elements, just that i can throw it all in a single string that I can delimit (with \n in this case)...

Answer (score 0):

Provided that:

- You only have intertwined `h3` and `ul` elements till the end of the wrapping div
- no other element can appear in this structure instead of `ul`
- no other element can appear in this structure instead of `h3`

and that your example is representative, this should do the trick.

```
//ul[count(following-sibling::h3) = count(following-sibling::ul)]
```

If you have other elements in the same place as the `ul` but there is always only one between the `h3`s, you can use this expression

```
//ul[count(following-sibling::h3) = count(following-sibling::*[not(local-name() = 'h3')])]
```

As for grouping the `h3` elements and the `ul` elements following them immediately, I don't think this is feasible in XPath alone. You'll need to do this in Ruby. I suggest searching for the `div` elements and parsing them imperatively, while counting the nodes and grouping the odd and even `h3`s and `ul`s together

Comment: There is no guarantee what will appear between the h3 headings. Also, I need to associate the content under the heading with the heading for insertion into a database.

Comment: @user1550052 can you provide a more exhaustive example then?

Comment: OK. I've included 3 divs from a sample inspection page. There could be more or less, but this is a complete example.

Comment: @user1550052 the XPath I provided seems to work for your updated example but it only selects the `ul`s. As for grouping the `h3` elements and the `ul` elements following them immediately, I don't think this is feasible in XPath alone. You'll need to do this in Ruby. I suggest searching for the `div` elements and parsing them imperatively, while counting the nodes and grouping the odd and even `h3`s and `ul`s together.